# Response from HTTP with GET method with params using axios in React Native

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, httprequest, axios

I think this might be a very simple question but I'm new to Web requests and can get it working nor get a simple response searching the web

I have a site from which I can get a JSON response by putting this URL into the browser: `http://www.test.com/callservice.php?action=stop&x=1&y=2&ct=100`

This in turn gives me some JSON response.

Now, I'm trying to get the same in Javascript using Axios.

Either using the URL directly

```
 componentWillMount() {
    axios.get('http://www.test.com/callservice.php?action=stop&x=1&y=2&ct=100')
      .then(response => console.log(response));
  }
```

Or by using the GET params:

```
 componentWillMount() {
    axios.get('http://www.test.com/callservice.php', {
      params: {
        action: 'stop',
        x: 1,
        y: 2,
        ct=100
      }
    })
      .then(response => console.log(response));
  }
```

But both approaches give the same error:

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Network Error
Error: Network Error
```

And a more detailed error from catching:

```
Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:15)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:87)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (event-target.js:172)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (XMLHttpRequest.js:542)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (XMLHttpRequest.js:378)
    at XMLHttpRequest.js:482
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (EventEmitter.js:181)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (MessageQueue.js:236)
    at MessageQueue.js:108
    at guard (MessageQueue.js:46)
```

Comment: try adding a catch clause to see the error: axios.get('http://www.testsite.com/pl/ite/callservice.php?action=nearthat&x=-1.61116871892648&y=50.1449621509454&maxct=100')
      .then(response => console.log(response)).catch(e => console.log(e));

Comment: @DiogoSgrillo I did that and added the full error to the question, but I still can't understand what is the issue.

Comment: Official docs format response differently. Can you try this format?
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
})

Comment: @SergChernata Can you please clarify what should I do?

Comment: Also, I've changed to the real URL in case it helps debugging.

Comment: Replace this in your code with the line I sent above. .then(response => console.log(response));

Comment: @SergChernata Ah ok, missed the `function`. I replaced it and the error message remains exactly the same.

Comment: @jbssm ok now add .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });

Answer (score 1):

jbssm,
It seems you are working on IOS. Can you check your App Transport Security Settings in Project Setings with Xcode.

Xcode disable http connection as default only allows secure connection.
You should add "Allow Arbitary Loads" to your Project Settings

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) issue.

If you are the owner of the script (on the server), you can add the appropriated response header for handling this issue. In PHP would be something like this:

`<?php
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`

For testing purposes (or if you don't have access to the server), you can install a [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) which disables the cross-domain restrictions.

Comment: But this works when I request the URL in the browser (Chrome or any other one I tried), what it doesn't work is in Javascript/React Native

Comment: The majority of browsers has security restrictions when handling Ajax requests. You can disable those restrictions in Chrome with the plugin I suggested.